# La base de datos me guarda los numeros en negativos

Tags: mysql

Tengo un api en laravel que se guarda los datos de un usuario. Yo envio los datos a traves de angular y cuando guardo el telefono que en mi país son de 10 digitos este en la base de datos se guarda como negativo. También lo intente con postman y le envie los siguientes datos.

```
{
    "Nombre": "Prueba",
    "Apellidos": "Prueba",
    "Email": "prueba@mail.com",
    "Fecha_HD": "2020-05-19",
    "Identificacion": 113515,
    "Telefono": 3006933873,
    "IP_Equipo": "xx.x.xx.xx"
}
```

Pero cuando se inserta en la base de datos el telefono se transforma en

```
{
    "Identificacion": 113515,
    "Nombre": "Prueba",
    "Apellidos": "Prueba",
    "Email": "prueba@mail.com",
    "Telefono": "-1136852281",
    "Fecha_HD": "2020-05-19",
    "IP_Equipo": "xx.x.xx.xx"
}
```

Este es el codígo de mi api en laravel para insertar los usuarios.

```
public function store(StoreUsuariosPost $request)
    {
        return Usuarios::create($request->validated());
    }
```

Y estas son mis reglas de validacion

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Identificacion' => 'required|min:4|max:200',
            'Nombre' => 'required|min:4|max:200',
            'Apellidos' => 'required|min:4|max:200',
            'Email' => 'required|min:4|max:200',
            'Telefono' => 'required',
            'Fecha_HD' => 'min:1|max:500',
            'IP_Equipo' => 'min:1|max:500',
        ];

    }
```

Tambíen adjunto la estructura de la base de datos. Tal vez el problema se encuentre ahí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Generalmente con un número telefónico no se realizan operaciones, por lo que con guardarlo (opino) como varchar alcanzaría o en todo caso como integer

Comment: Aun así, se coloca el número como negativo.

Comment: @BetaM con integer te quedas corto. Los numeros de telefono no son numeros!!! son una codificacion que se basa en numeros, pero se debe guardar como varchar. El numero en si, como numero, puede ser enorme (imaginate el mio con codigo de pais y todo 0541112345678) ademas que por ahi requieras el 0 adelante.. te lo guarda como negativo porque se pasa del maximo

Comment: no, no es un numero! que haces si pongo un cero adelante para que se entienda que es internacional? @BetaM

Comment: Los números telefónicos se guardan como texto (varchar o char) pues con ellos nunca vas a realizar operaciones.

Comment: Los números telefónicos se deben guardar como varchar debido a casos como: "+34 ...", "09...." y otros

Comment: Lo comprendo @gbianchi creeme :), lo único que me resta es editar esta pregunta pues el problema no es de Laravel en si

Comment: Lo coloque como varchar y aun asi el problema persiste.

Comment: no.. ahora tenes que sanitizar tus datos.. lo hiciste? no van a cambiar los numeros solo porque cambiaste el tipo de dato... lo probaste nuevamente?

Comment: Por curiosidad, si haces una consulta directamente en la BBDD (con MySQL cliente, o phpmyadmin o el que utilices habitualmente) el valor te vuelve negativo? Más que nada para confirmar que se están almacenado en negativo, y que no es una mala conversión en la lectura...

Comment: @gbianchi como sanizo los datos?

Comment: Y eso lo sabras vos.. pero todos los numeros que estaban negativos, ahora siguen siendo negativos...pero son strings.. no sabria decirte como hacer para arreglarlos...

Comment: @gbianchi pero sigo enviando los datos por el postman y los guarda como negativo aún. A pesar de que esta definido como varchar.

Comment: Estas seguro que modificaste la DB que correspondia? los datos llegan bien? el query en tu base de datos tambien devuelve datos negativos?

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate en estas líneas:

```
"Apellidos": "Prueba",
"Identificacion": 113515,
"Telefono": 3006933873,
```

Según la BBDD los tipos de campos son:

Apellidos -> varchar

Identificacion -> Double

Telefono -> varchar

Creo que le estas pasando un valor numérico (telefono) a un varchar. Prueba de pasárselo como cadena (String) a ver si el problema se corrige.